# TypeScript - Check if given 'any' parameter is custom type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, typeof, type-assertion

I have a function template like this:

```
function (..., args: any) {...}
```

And I have a class called `CreateLobbyParameter` :

```
export class CreateLobbyParameter {
    userId: number;
    gameMode: GameMode;
}
```

If given `any` typed args parameter is not similar to `CreateLobbyParameter` (e.g. `{userId: 0, gameMode: 0}`, but not `{userId:0}`); I wanna handle that situation.

I've tried `typeof(arg as CreateLobbyParameter)`, but it returns the string `"object"` for the parameter `{userId: 0, gameMode: 0}`, and not `CreateLobbyParameter.`

Also, `arg instanceof CreateLobbyParameter` returns false.

Comment: Not very clear what are you trying to do, are you trying to type a function that takes `any` as an argument?

Comment: Is `GameMode` an enumeration or another class?

Comment: You should probably define an interface for `args` instead of typing it as `any`.

Comment: GameMode is an enum.

Comment: Johnny,  but it's properties are flexible,  they change depending to its place.

Comment: TypeScript is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat it like JavaScript.

```
var userId = arg.userId;
var gameMode = arg.gameMode;
if (userId && gameMode) {
   var myCreateLobbyParameter = new CreateLobbyParameter {
      userId = userId,
      gameMode = gameMode
   }
}
```

Then you have a real `CreateLobbyParameter` object to work with, or you can do whatever with a non-conforming argument.

Comment: I have `noImplicitAny` option turned on, but let me try to adapt the code.

Comment: This worked out, when I gave `any` types to them, thanks for helping.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another way:

```
export function isSimilar(object: any, target: any): boolean {
    if (typeof(object) !== object && (typeof(object) !== typeof(target))) {
        return true;
    }
    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(object);
    const targetKeys: string[] = Object.keys(target);
    return !keys.every(x => targetKeys.indexOf(x) >= 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
hasNull(args, new CreateLobbyParameter());
```